# error TS2339: Property 'read' does not exist on type

Tags: javascript, angular

src/app/components/product/product-read/product-read.component.ts:17:25 - error TS2339: Property 'read' does not exist on type 'ProductService'. 17 this.productService.read().subscribe(products => {

this is the error i got, and on line 17 is the error and is the same in the video guide i learning and i dont know what to do.

```
import { Product } from './../product.model';
import { ProductService } from './../product.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-read',
  templateUrl: './product-read.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-read.component.css']
})
export class ProductReadComponent implements OnInit {

  products!: Product[]

  constructor(private productService:ProductService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.productService.read().subscribe(products => {
      this.products = products
      console.log(products)
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you have this method `read()` in your productService ?
If not then this is why he is saying you have error.
Can you share with us the code of the `Product Service`

Comment: read(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.baseUrl)

this is on my product.service.ts

Comment: Somehow i make this work, i think i dindt save after some modifications

Comment: @leopietazzoli No problem.
I wish all the best in your learning.
Mistakes happens.